# How to use Future.wait with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, future, wait, sublist

Actually, I have many sublists and I have to display it one by one after recieving a signal (list contains[170,204]).
that's why I have to use Future.wait. But this didn't work for me. what happens actually is that I send the first sublist then I resend the same sublist and after this there was no sublist sended.
But when I tried to change the future.wait by Future.delayed it worked as expected. so the problem is on how I used the Future .wait
this is my code :

```
  getValue() {
    _characteristic42?.value.listen(
        (notification) async => {print("Notification Value : $notification")});
  }
if (notification[0] == 170 && notification[1] == 204)
                  {
                    await Future.forEach(chun, (ch) async {
                      
                      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 4));
                      await c.write(ch, withoutResponse: true);
                      await c.read();
                      await Future.wait(getValue());
                    })
```

I would be very thankful if you can help me resolving this issue

Comment: your `getValue` is not a Future function so that doesn't work

Comment: @eamirho3ein how can I update it please !

Comment: what do you want to get from that? to see it prints?

Comment: actually the getValue should returns a list : [170,204]

Comment: why did you add the delay? is it required to delay before `c.write` ? @rania

Comment: @pmatatias it's not required but just to wait 4sec before sending the first sublist

Answer (score 0):

```
 await Future.wait([
  FirstFutureFunction(),
  secondFutureFunction(),
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 approach to handle Future function. with `await` and with `then`.
here an article i wrote to explain it: [await vs then in Flutter](https://pmatatias.medium.com/await-vs-then-in-flutter-28c2ce600cea)

actually without `Future.wait`, your current code its already interupt the process before execute next function. because you are using `await`.

i think you missed this meaning:   this `=>` syntax means your function return 1 argument.in your code,it will return the print notification value.

solution:

```
getValue() {
  _characteristic42?.value.listen(
        (notification) async {
 print("Notification Value : $notification"));

if (notification[0] == 170 && notification[1] == 204)
{
  await c.write(yoursublist, withoutResponse: true);
  await c.read();
  });
 }
}
```

with the code above, its already execute line by line.

in that article i had explain the detail by example.

Comment: yes I know but I want that for each notification[0] == 170 && notification[1] == 204 I have to send the next sublist not only for the first notification[0] == 170 && notification[1] == 204

Comment: @rania, updated my answer, how about that?

Comment: this won't work on my code because getValue and c.write are separated